# Enabling drag move in Spark List while not allowing copying elements using ctrl+click

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, air, flex-spark, flex4.6

I'm having an issue with a Spark List control in a Flex 4.6 AIR app.  It's a screen with a single List that we want the user to be able to reorder the items in the list.  I am able to get the reordering to work fine.  The issue is that you are able to create new items in the list by holding down CTRL will drag/dropping the items.  I've tried to do some googling on this problem but have not yet been able to find a way to get around this.  Does anybody have any ideas?  Any help is greatly appreciated!

Here is the code I am using for the list:

```
 <s:List id="sampleList" left="10" top="10"
                alternatingItemColors="[0xEFF3FA, 0xFFFFFF]" dataProvider="@{sampleItems.list}"
                dragEnabled="true" dragMoveEnabled="true" dropEnabled="true"
                labelField="name"
                right="10" bottom="72"
                width="300" height="350"/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way I could find to do this was to put a handler on one of the drag events and checking whether or not the user was moving the item.

```
 private function dragHandler(event:DragEvent):void
 {
      if (event.action != 'move')
      {
           event.preventDefault();
      }
 }

 <s:List id="sampleList" left="10" top="10" dragDrop="dragHandler(event);"
            alternatingItemColors="[0xEFF3FA, 0xFFFFFF]" dataProvider="@{sampleItems.list}"
            dragEnabled="true" dragMoveEnabled="true" dropEnabled="true"
            labelField="name"
            right="10" bottom="72"
            width="300" height="350"/>
```